# U0670 support for BlackBerry development

Tags: java, blackberry, unicode

I am developing an application that requires me to post content in Arabic text. As of now I am using UTF-8 and the words are appearing fine. However there are certain words that are getting chopped into two. My client wants me to use Unicode Character 'ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF' (U+0670). I want to know if this unicode is supported in BlackBerry or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of supported charset check
http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=0FDE6789F61D444C44606FD257457AE2?externalId=KB04262&sliceId=1&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl

Comment: @rashmi also check this,http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp